# Centre of Mass, Moment of Inertia and Lagrangian of a triangular laminate

Tags: geometry, triangles, classical-mechanics, applications

A triangular laminate has vertices $O = (0, 0), A = (0, a)$ and $B = (a, 0)$ and
constant density $ρ_0$.

(i) Calculate the position of the centre of mass and show that the moment of inertia about the axis perpendicular to the plane of the laminate and passing through O is given by $\frac 13M a^2$, where $M$ is the mass of the laminate.

(ii) A pendulum consists of the triangular laminate which swings freely in a vertical
plane about a horizontal axis through O .
Show that the Lagrangian is given by
$$L =\frac16Ma^2θ^2 +\frac M3\sqrt 2ga \cos θ$$
where M is the mass of the laminate and θ is an angle which should be defined.

(iii) Calculate the period of small oscillations about the downward vertical.

Can i merely state the centre of mass is given by $X=\frac a3 \ Y=\frac a3$? Would I need a double integral to find the moment of inertia?

Answer (score 0):

You are right: the center of mass of a triangular lamina lies at the triangle centroid, i.e. it is the common point of its medians.

To see why, consider a thin stripe of the lamina, parallel to a side of the triangle: its center of mass is obviously at its midpoint, and it thus lies on the median corresponding to that side. The lamina can be seen as the sum of such thin stripes, whose centers of mass all lie on the same median: the center of mass of the whole lamina must therefore lie on that median too.

The same reasoning can be repeated for the other two medians, hence the center of mass of the lamina must be at the centroid of the triangle.

As for the moment of inertia, you can avoid the double integral by noticing that the moment of inertia at point $(a/2,a/2)$ is half that of a square at its center, and using then Steiner's theorem.

EDIT.

If you insist on computing the moment of inertia around $O$ with an integral, here it is:
$$
I=\int_0^a\int_0^{a-x}\rho(x^2+y^2)\,dy\,dx,
$$
where $\rho$ is the surface density and $M={1\over2}\rho a^2$.

Comment: What would my limits of integration be??

Comment: So you want to compute a double integral? Why? I explained how you can avoid that, once you know that the moment of inertia of a square lamina around its center is $Ma^2/6$. By the way: I get $Ma^2/9$ instead of $Ma^2/3$, are you sure of that result?

Comment: No, sorry: the result you quoted is right. I misread the question and thought $O$ was the center of mass! But the method I outlined works in both cases. Anyway I edited my answer to show the integral.

Comment: The moment of inertia of a laminate about a perpendicular axis through $ (a/2,a/2) $ is $ \frac {Ma^{2}} {6} $ and this the same for the triangular laminate by symmetry. Using the Parallel Axis Theorem you subtract for the distance to the centroid of the triangular laminate and then add for the distance to $ O $ giving $ \frac {Ma^{2}} {6} - \frac {Ma^{2}} {18} + \frac {2Ma^{2}} {9} = \frac {Ma^{2}} {3} $.

Comment: Thanks so much! How would I go about (ii)? Form equations for T and V and sub into L=T-V? I just don't know what to set theta to.

Comment: Yes: $L=T-V$, remembering that for a rotating body $T={1\over2}I\dot\theta^2$, where I is the moment of inertia about the rotation axis. (Notice that in your formula you wrote by mistake $\theta$ instead of $\dot\theta$).